# CSS transition border and background at the same time

Tags: css, css-transitions

I want to change background color and border color on hover at the same time. I use:

```
transition: all 0.5s ease;    
-vendors-transition: all 0.5s ease;
```

but background-color changes immediately.

Comment: It does work fine actually. think something else is over-riding the styles. Since fiddle works fine : http://jsfiddle.net/nLeVx/1/ Can you check for any other `:hover` , possibly parent divs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working code,

```css
#yourdiv {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 5px solid black;    
  transition: border 500ms ease-out; 
  -webkit-transition: border 500ms ease-out; 
  -moz-transition: border 500ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: border 500ms ease-out;
}

#yourdiv:hover{
  border: 10px solid red;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've tried this by specifying the properties separately and it works, perhaps the `all` keyword is failing?

```css
div:hover {
    background-color: blue;
    border-color: black;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease, border-color 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s ease, border-color 0.5s ease;
    /* please note that transitions are not supported in IE 9 and there is no -ms prefix */
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease, border-color 0.5s ease;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xzEsh/)

**Update:** I think I understand your question. You want the transition to reverse upon unhovering. In that case you will need the transition properties on the non-hovered element as well (the one without `:hover`):

```css
div {
    width: 10rem;
    height: 10rem;
    background-color: purple;
    border: thick solid orange;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease, border-color 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s ease, border-color 0.5s ease;
    /* please note that transitions are not supported in IE 9 and there is no -ms prefix */
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease, border-color 0.5s ease;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xzEsh/4/)